# Странность с индексацией массива в классе

Tags: массивы, классы, c++

Простое учебное задание по классам, реализовать класс "строка", содержащий поля длина и массив символов не больше 1024 символов(то есть, нулл-терминейтед, вообще говоря, не являющийся). Класс почти успешно дописан и протестен, но на реализации самого последнего оператора == возник затык, разобраться в котором не могу. В общем, в процессе дебага неправильной работы этого самого == нашел такую вещь: в окне Evaluate/Modify (дело происходит в турбо си) обнаруживаю (имеющаяся строка "Lorem Ipsum", соответственно, длина 11, после последней буквы m в массиве находится еще какой-то мусор):

```
i = 0
this->ch[0] = 'L' (правильно)
this->ch[i] = 'T' (WTF?)
```

Проход по строке типа `this->ch[i+1], this->ch[i+2]` и т.д. дает аналогичный мусор, явно содержанию строки не соответствующий. При обращении через экземпляр `ts.ch[i]` происходит то же самое. Что интересно, все методы, которые использовали посимвольное обращение к строкам, отработали без проблем, проблема впервые возникла на этапе сравнения `this->ch[i]==ts.ch[i]`. Вполне вероятно, что дело в двух часах ночи и моей собственной непроходимой тупости, но пока я склонен списывать это на какую-то черную магию.

Comment: Чуток больше исходника покажите

Comment: Именно. Очень интересуют конструкторы класса и оператор ==.

Comment: Покажите самое главное - перегрузку оператора "==" !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось очень уныло и разбило мою веру в магию :3 См. ответ.

UPD: упс, нельзя. Тогда так: оказывается, что отладчик вовсе не всемогущ и в некоторых ситуациях показывает чушь. В частности, вот такую вот индексацию он в силу каких-то особенностей реализации не тянет. При этом выполняется все полностью корректно. Ну, и на всякий случай, в реализации == я просто проморгал, что на посимвольное равенство случайно проверяю через =, поэтому и не работало...